# Can anyone see why i get UnBoundLocal Error for my score varible

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone see why I get "UnBoundLocal Error" for my `score` varible?

```
import random
Score=0
def Main_Menu(Score):
    print("=============================")
    print("WELCOME TO MY QUIZ")
    print("=============================")
    while True:
        Username=input("What is your name?")
        if Username.isalpha():
            if len(Username)>11:
                print("You are only a maximum of 11 characters")
            else:
                Username=Username.title()
                break
        else:
            print("Letters only")
    while True:
        while True:
            Option=input("What do you want to do?\n1 For Quiz\n2 To Quit.")
            if Option.isdigit():
                Option=int(Option)
                break
            else:
                print("Numbers Only.")
        if Option==1:
            for x in range(10):
                Quiz(Username)
            print("You have scored",Score,"point out of 10!!\n")
        elif Option==2:
            input("Press Enter to quit the program")
            break
        else:
            print("You only have 2 options")

    Quiz(Username)
def Quiz(Username):
    Tries=3
    Number_One=random.randint (0,10)
    Number_Two=random.randint (0,10)
    Arithmetic_Operator=random.choice(["+","-","*",])
    if Arithmetic_Operator=="+":
        print(Username,"\nWhat is",Number_Two,"+",Number_One,"?")
        Answer=Number_Two+Number_One      
    elif Arithmetic_Operator=="-":
        print(Username,"\nWhat is",Number_Two,"-",Number_One,"?")
        Answer=Number_Two-Number_One
    elif Arithmetic_Operator=="*":
        print(Username,"\nWhat is",Number_Two,"*",Number_One,"?")
        Answer=Number_Two*Number_One 
    while Tries!=0:
        while True:
           Guess=input("Answer: ")
           if Guess.isdigit():
                Guess=int(Guess)    
                break
           else:

                print("Numbers Only.")
        if Guess==Answer:
            print("Well Done.You got it right.\nYou have a point")
            Score=Score+1

            break
        elif Guess!=Answer:
            Tries=Tries-1
            print("You  have",Tries,"tries left")
        if Tries==0:
            print("The answer is",Answer)

Main_Menu(Score)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Score' referenced before assignment` error because the `Quiz` method doesn't have a local variable `Score` but is trying to read from it. You probably meant to use the the global variable `Score`, but it's not available in the method scope without using the `global` statement. You can fix this by adding `global Score` in the beginning of the `Quiz` method.

However, using globals in python code is another discussion, I would strongly recommend avoiding them, unless there's really a proper reason to use them. Please see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error) for more details and discussion.

Comment: Thank you for your help.